Failed to realize static UTType instance 0x600002fc47a0 for identifier com.my_custom_type.test. The faulting component was unknown at runtime
I am creating an app for MacOS using SwiftUI. I want to export a custom file type from the app. To start off simple, I started by having my custom file type conform to public.plain-text so that I can write basic text into my file and be able to open it with Text Edit.
Under the info section of my app's target, I have created the following Exported Type Identifier and Document Type:


I also added the same information into the info.plist file.
Here is my code:
// adding my own file extension to UTTypes
extension UTType{
    static let custom_type = UTType(exportedAs: "com.my_custom_type.test")
    
}


struct ExportCustomDataType: View {
    
    @State var fileName:String = "testFile"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("File Name: ")
                TextField(text: $fileName) {
                    Text("This is the label")
                }
                .frame(width: 150)
            }
            Button("Export Custom File Type") {
                exportCustomFile(FileName: fileName)
//                savePanel()
//                exportViaFileWrapper(FileName: fileName)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

func exportCustomFile(FileName:String){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let downloadsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let fileURL = downloadsURL.appendingPathComponent(FileName, conformingTo: .custom_type)

    let data = "Writing to file".data(using: .utf8)

    do {
        try data!.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("Error saving file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
}

func exportViaFileWrapper(FileName:String){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let downloadsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let fileURL = downloadsURL.appendingPathComponent(FileName, conformingTo: .custom_type)
    
    var fileWrapper = FileWrapper()
    
    do{
        try writeMyCustomFile(to: &fileWrapper, contentType: .custom_type)
        try fileWrapper.write(to: fileURL, originalContentsURL: nil)
    } catch{
        print("there was an error writing the file")
    }
}

func savePanel(){
    let panel = NSSavePanel()
    
    panel.allowedContentTypes = [.custom_type]
    
    let response = panel.runModal()
    
    let data = "Writing to file".data(using: .utf8)
    
    if (response == .OK){
        try! data?.write(to: panel.url!)
    }
}

func writeMyCustomFile(to fileWrapper: inout FileWrapper, contentType: UTType) throws{
    let data = "Writing to file".data(using: .utf8)!
    fileWrapper = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: data)
}


#Preview {
    ExportCustomDataType()
}

When I run the following code, a file is created, but it is just a document type. It does not have my custom extension or a different file type. Whenever I create the file, I get the following warning message: "Failed to realize static UTType instance 0x600002fc47a0 for identifier com.my_custom_type.test. The faulting component was unknown at runtime."
I created a NSOpenPanel and set the allowed file type to my custom file type. The panel would not let me open any of the files I have created, so I guess that confirms those files are not registered with my type.
How can I fix this issue and create a file with a custom type?
